# kill is unsafe respect to signals - any alternative?

Tags: c, unix, signals, kill, signal-handling

I read that [kill](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html) is unsafe respect to signals [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html).

What else should I use if I want to kill child process as part of clean up inside my signal handler? What are my alternatives?

Comment: where did you read that kill is unsafe? and what do you mean by unsafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misread, that page says that `kill()` (and everything else in the table) shall be async-signal-safe. anything not in the table is to be considered unsafe.