# Pass local variable to a signal handler function

Tags: c, linux, signals, kill

I want to send a copy of some data to a signal handler function, take the simplified example:

```
signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
```

```
void handler(int sig){
    
    //...
    _exit(some_variable);
}
```

The goal is to stop the process and make it return `some_variable` value to the parent without making it a global variable. Mind that `some_variable` is local to the project that catches the signal, not the process that raises the signal.

I woud like to be able to both raise the signal in another process ([kill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)) (not the parent btw) and to be able to do it from a console ([kill](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill)) or using a script, and that's the main reason for using [`signal()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html), as it's good for both.

I understand that there are other ways of doing this but would really like to know if this can be done using `signal()` or a related method.

Other threads on the site suggest that this can't be done like this but they are quite old, perhaps some newer solution exists.

Comment: You can't safely use `exit()` in a signal handler, btw, just `_exit()` or `_Exit()`. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: Who will raise the `SIGUSR1` signal? Because if you use [`sigaction`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with the `SA_SIGINFO` flag set, then depending on how the signal was raised would allow user-specified data to be passed to the signal handler.

Comment: And you can pass information to a signal handler with `sigaction()` using `SA_SIGINFO` and `sigqueue()`.

Comment: I found a nice duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970224/providing-passing-argument-to-signal-handler voted to close my own question, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the signal is sent from the same process, just use a global variable. There is no basis/justification for objecting to using a global variable here, because **signal dispositions are already global variables**. That is, by committing yourself to installing a handler for `SIGUSR1` and choosing a purpose for it, you've already chosen to have a singleton here; adding a variable as part of that singleton is no further sin. However in this case (same process) there's probably no reason to be using a signal handler anyway. There are all sorts of far-less-dangerous ways to communicate between parts of your program.

If the signal is being sent from a different process, you can pass small amounts of data (one integer) via `union sigval` queued with `sigqueue`, but that only works for `sigqueue`; it doesn't work if you want to be able to just use the `kill` command. And once you choose to require a special tool to interact, it makes a lot more sense to drop signals and use some better IPC mechanism like unix sockets, named pipes, shared memory with some synchronization primitives (semaphore or mutex+condvar) living inside it, etc.